# partial class can't be created in ria service library

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

When create .NET Ria Service Class Library, VS will create two projects:
MyRiaServices(client side)
MyRiaServices.Web(server side)

Suppose my entity model is in another project:
MyData(entity framework)

There is an Entity People.

Then I want to use partial class to extend this entity in following way:

```
namespace MyData
{
   public partial class Person
    {
    //....
    }
}
```

If I do it in project MyData, it is fine.

But I want to do this way in project MyRiaServices.Web so that I can named the file as as person.shared.cs, but I failed. It give me error saying class definition conflict etc.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a partial class this way.  The objective of the `partial` keyword is to allow two or more source files in compilation to contribute to the complete code of a single type.  This allows auto-generated code created by designers to sit in a separate file from developer written code that then form a single class like `Person`.

However this mechisim is a compile time thing.  You can't have an assembly expose a `partial` type which can be extended further with code compiled into a different assembly.

See the definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28VS.80%29.aspx).